# Adobe Analytics Slicing Tags

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics

I have an iOS app where I have analytics setup (as most people do) that tracks a whole set of different scenarios. In a few of them, the data I send with the tag doesn't all get sent. What I mean by this is best demonstrated with an example. If I send the following data as a tag in one of my analytics:

```
User successfully logged into the app and hit the homescreen
```

Now, I wouldn't normally send all of that in just one tag, it would get broken up, but for example purposes, pretend that's what I want to send. For quite a few users, tags like this will get sliced up into all sorts of different tags, so when I actually look in SiteCatalyst, I end up seeing a bunch of tags that may resemble something like so:

```
successfully logg
nd hit the homescreen
User successfully logged into the app and hit the homescreen
User successfully logg
```

And so on. It breaks it up into a bunch of different parts, and then displays them all as separate tags. The ones that are affected get broken up into 15-20 different tags all of which are different parts of the full tag.

Here is the hard part: I can't reproduce the issue. I'm trying, but haven't been able to yet. I also am not very well versed in Adobe analytics and am not sure how the backend setup is for us on SiteCat.

Because of my inexperience with analytics, I'm not sure what more data may be helpful. My code doesn't do any truncation, it simply calls `trackAppState:withContextData:`, and the tags in my contextData get truncated like I showed.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Has anyone seen anything similar? Or could anyone point me in a direction that may get me started looking into this issue? I'm really at a loss of how to go about debugging this issue.

Edit: One piece of info that just hit me! I build up the tag in question (at least the current one I'm trying to reproduce, for all I know there are other tags that get truncated that aren't built up like this, I haven't gotten a chance to look into all of them yet.) using `-[NSString stringWithFormat:] and take the errorMessage that is returned as my message, so it's a dynamic tag.

It may have something to do with the `stringWithFormat:` message? Again, very lost as to where to even start with this one.

Answer (score 1):

can you give us a sample of the code you use to call the trackAppState?

If it can help you you can enable debug logging for the Adobe Analytics library calling the method [ADBMobile setDebugLogging:YES]; in the appDidFinishLaunchingWithOption.
In this way you can see in the console how Adobe send the data.

You can also use the tool "Bloodhound" which is a proxy App developed by Adobe expecially for osx in order to let you sniff all the info sent by your App in real time, you can find it in the help section of the mobile marketing interface.

Thanks,

Claudio.